# Find the wieght of each element of another vector

Tags: r

I have a vector `v` and I want to have a vector `w` which is the weight of each element of v. How can I get the result (vector `w`)in R? For example,

```
    v = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6)
    u = unique(v)
    w = c(2, 3, 1, 4, 2, 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `table`:

```
table(v)
v
0 1 3 4 5 6 
2 3 1 4 2 1
```

Comment: another option is using `tabulate` which'll give the numbers from 1 to n by default. you can use `tabulate(v + min(v)+1)`. And remove any 0's later.

Comment: How can I remove unique vector u form your answer? I just need vector w as result.

Comment: @Arun. If  v is random number, I think we can not use your mentioned code.

Comment: @rose, what I meant with *by default gives numbers from 1 to n* is when the numbers are integers (which is in your example).